# Hierarchical Oracle inserts. Ensure that every parent has at most one child

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

My sample database has a table that stores employees, where the employee_id is the primary key and the manager_id is a foreign key to the employee_id

[image]

What is shown in the picture below is a hierarchical structure in a company. 
The employee_id has no manager (it is the boss!), the 1021 manages 1022.

When I execute

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id, manager_id, LEVEL
      FROM my_employees
      START WITH employee_id = 1020
      CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;
```

I am taking back the hierarchy of the company:

```
LAST_NAME                 EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID      LEVEL
------------------------- ----------- ---------- ----------
Test                             1020                     1
Test2                            1021       1020          2
Test3                            1022       1021          3
```

I would like to enhance this functionality in order to verify that each parent (ie EMPLOYEE_ID) will have a unique (ONE) child only.

For example this is possible in my table:

```
LAST_NAME                 EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID      LEVEL
------------------------- ----------- ---------- ----------
Test                             1020                     1
Test2                            1021       1020          2
Test3                            1022       1021          3
Test4                            1023       1021          3
```

Test4 and Test3 have the same manager (test3 and test4 are one the same level).

My request is to find an easy way in the database schema to ensure that "an employee can not have two managers no matter the level" AND a manager cannot have more than 1 employees that belong to the next level.

The sql script that created my table/trigger and sequence is the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence MY_EMPLOYEES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1020 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL ;


--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table MY_EMPLOYEES
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" 
   (    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "PHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "HIRE_DATE" DATE, 
    "SALARY" NUMBER(8,0), 
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES"."EMPLOYEE_ID" IS 'The primary key';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES"."FIRST_NAME" IS 'First Name';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES"."LAST_NAME" IS 'Last Name';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES"."EMAIL" IS 'Email Id';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES"."PHONE_NUMBER" IS 'Phone Number
';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES"."HIRE_DATE" IS 'Hire Date';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES"."SALARY" IS 'Enfornced by check';
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index MY_EMPLOYEES_UK1
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES_UK1" ON "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" ("EMAIL") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index MY_EMPLOEES_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "HR"."MY_EMPLOEES_PK" ON "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Trigger MY_EMPL_TRIG_1
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "HR"."MY_EMPL_TRIG_1" 
   before insert on "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" 
   for each row 
begin  
   if inserting then 
      if :NEW."EMPLOYEE_ID" is null then 
         select MY_EMPLOYEES_SEQ.nextval into :NEW."EMPLOYEE_ID" from dual; 
      end if; 
   end if; 
end;


/
ALTER TRIGGER "HR"."MY_EMPL_TRIG_1" ENABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table MY_EMPLOYEES
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" MODIFY ("EMPLOYEE_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" MODIFY ("LAST_NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" MODIFY ("EMAIL" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" MODIFY ("HIRE_DATE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" ADD CONSTRAINT "MY_EMPLOEES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" ADD CONSTRAINT "MY_EMPLOYEES_UK1" UNIQUE ("EMAIL")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" ADD CONSTRAINT "MY_EMPLOYEES_CHK1" CHECK (salary > 0) ENABLE;
```

Comment: IF I understand it right you just need to add an Unique Index on manager_id column allowing nulls, of course, although this requirement is very strange.

Comment: @JorgeCampos how can I do what you are describing? Why is this strange?

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by each parent has a unique child.

Comment: Makes no sense a company where a manager (here is what you call as parent) have only one subordinate. A manager can have many subordinates. The other way around is more feasibly: A child can only have one parent. `1->2, 1->3, 1->4, 2->5` what you are asking is that `1` in my sample can only be parent of one of 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: @JBC Each manager should have at most one employee at the same level

Comment: Could you explain who is a parent and who is a child in the abov example ?
 Is `1021` a parent of `1022` and `1023` ? If yes, then this negates your requirement `each parent must have ONE child`. Maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: I really think that you messed up with words there. I think that what you want is that a manager can have many employee but an employee can not have two managers no matter the level.

Comment: You see everyone here is saying the same as me. Either you described your problem wrong or understand it wrong to explain to us.

Comment: @JorgeCampos you are right, let me correct my question. However you said it above: The correct is that :an employee can not have two managers no matter the level.

Comment: So, just `create unique index uk_unique_employee on mytable (EMPLOYEE_ID)` should be enough. Unless there are more requirements that we don't know.

Comment: @JorgeCampos updated the question. Each employee can not have more than 1 managers, and each manager can not have more than one employees at the next level.

Comment: That unique will also guarantee that. To fulfill your requirement you only need one row per employee.

Comment: @JorgeCampos looks OK, you may answer the question just for the record...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148923/discussion-between-cateof-and-jorge-campos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create an [Unique Index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#ADMIN11725) on your table to ensure that no Employee will be duplicated avoid that an Employee will have more than one Manager.

```
create unique index uk_unique_employee on "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" (EMPLOYEE_ID);
```

**EDIT**

About your last comment: "Jorge, what is wrong wit the table is that it possible to create a employee with a manager that does not EXIST."

So you just need to add a foreign key constraint to the `EMPLOYEE_ID` in the `MANAGER_ID` column like:

```
alter table "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" 
    add constraint fk_employee_manager
        foreign key (MANAGER_ID)
        references "HR"."MY_EMPLOYEES" (EMPLOYEE_ID);
```

Note that in order to create a FOREIGN KEY the column must be a primary key or have an index on it (which the previous command ensured).